# jquery - sliding pictures by scrolling down and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 background size pictures (759px each) that are confined inside a `<div>`.
I'm trying to make a function that by sliding a bit up would advance to the upper picture, and that by sliding down it would do the opposite.

I'v tried numerous different codes but none of them actually worked. 
I believe that the function shouldn't take too much coding so I will put here a short version of my code. Please help me with it and correct me if there is anything wrong here.

```
$('body','html').on('wheel scroll', function(event){

if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 <0)//mouse is receipting a down movement
{$('this').animate({scrollTo: '+=759px'},2000);}

else {$('this').animate({scrollTo: '+=759px'},2000);} //mouse is receipting an up movement

});
```

Comment: This code snippet is insufficient to look for the solution.